Как подключить CRYPTOMUS к боту на aiogram
Создаю бота на aiogram 3.
Нужна помощь с подключением CRYPTOMUS к боту.
Буду очень признателен если все распишите.

Для работы с API Cryptomus есть библиотека pyCryptomusAPI - можете попробовать поработать с ней.
Если Вам интересен наглядный пример интеграции с aiogram - есть проект AiogramTemplate. Автор использует свою дополнительную маленькую библиотеку multi-merchant - она позволяет работать с несколькими системами платежей. Конкретно здесь написан класс для работы с API Cryptomus (использует вышеуказанную библиотеку pyCryptomusAPI).
Можно перейти в репозитории и посмотреть как всё устроено внутри, взять себе необходимые моменты, адаптировать под себя. Проект выглядит довольно приличным, с неплохим количеством фич.
Плюс скорее всего придётся заглядывать в исходную документацию API Cryptomus.
